# Charging Tax on Freight/Shipping Amount in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way to charge sales tax on shipping/freight in Dynamics CRM 2011 with the Orders entity?

By default, CRM charges tax only on the Amount and considers the Freight as tax-exempt, however many regions (such as Canada) require that tax is charged on the shipping freight/amount.

Alternatively, is it possible to change the Total Tax calculation (a CRM managed field), from currently:

> Total Tax = (Detail Amount) * *TaxRate*

to:

> Total Tax = (Detail Amount + *Freight Amount*) * *TaxRate*

?

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom field called "Total tax (inc. freight)" with custom javascript to perform the calculation.

Comment: Using a plug-in would be a more robust solution to ensure business logic is enforced in all scenarios (e.g. a workflow updating the value on an order or orderline).

Comment: Thanks @user1173691, but as Greg mentioned we're specifically looking at doing this server side via a plug-in. At the moment, we're bypassing the Freight Amount, and instead creating a custom Product called 'Shipping' where we override the price, but still looking at ways to charge tax on shipping.

Answer (score 0):

We've ultimately decided to bypass the built-in Freight Amount calculation and just create shipping as a separate line item. Not the ideal solution, but at least it gives us full control on the tax charged for shipping.